# how to limit the type of an attribute in Cloudant

Tags: indexing, cloudant

I want to create a database in cloudant which can save time in it and then create a Index on the basis of that time. So in which format should I insert date and time in it so that the index will be able to arrange them in accordance with the time.

Answer (score 0):

A common option is to use [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss  (example: 2015-01-31T00:00:00)
```

Example json:

```
{
  "date": "2015-01-31T00:00:00"
}
```

Comment: How to Add This in Cloudant?, there is no such option available.

Comment: You don't need to declare data types up front with Cloudant.  Just add an attribute similar to the above example.